# One query for every number in row

Tags: php, mysql, database

If I have a database with a field called `items` with `'1,2,3,7,15,25,64,346'` in it.
Is there a function to use the commas as a separator and take each number and start a new query and get info for that id?  Like a `foreach` but in sql?

I can see it so clear but cannot put it in words...

Comment: or just point me to a question that is the same as mine...

Comment: '1,2,3,7,15,25,64,346'  is a single row data?

Comment: Use where in condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME in (1,2,3,7,15,25,64,346);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can use command **IN**

```
mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN ( 1,2,3,4,5 );' );
```

[WHERE - IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$row =  '1,2,3,7,15,25,64,346'; // $row = $field['value']
$arr = explode(',',$row);

foreach($arr as $a) {
  // write your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5 )` to find data having id's.

No need to separate the values. This will give you the desired result.

Comment: You and Rakesh Sharma mixed is exactly what I needed!  Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

There is so way to do a "SQL foreach". Do it using PhP

Also, having such fields means your database is not normalized. You should give a look at relational database normalization, otherwise the bigger your database will be, the bigger your problems will be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want data like this where 'source' is table having the column

```
SELECT target.* FROM target
LEFT JOIN source ON FIND_IN_SET(target.id, source.ids_row)
```